# Why can't I edit a commandbar control in Excel 2013 with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, commandbar

I'm trying to make my own drill-through action for PivotTable by means of VBA.
The action will be called from context menu of a PivotTable from **Additional Actions**.
I want to put my button under **Additional Actions** control of **PivotTable Context Menu** command bar.
The point is that by default **Additional Actions** already contains **(No Actions Defined)** item.
So, I want to remove this **(No Actions Defined)** after adding my button, but nothing works.
I cannot even change any property of **(No Actions Defined)** control, like Caption, Visible, etc.
What might be the reason, and what is the workaround?
Here is my code so far (you can put it under Workbook_SheetBeforeRightClick, for example, and then test with any Pivot Table in that workbook):

```
Dim PCell                   As PivotCell
Dim PComBar                 As CommandBar
Dim PControl                As CommandBarControl
Dim DControl                As CommandBarControl
Dim BControl                As CommandBarControl
Dim IsFromPivotTable        As Boolean

IsFromPivotTable = False
On Error GoTo NotFromPivot
Set PCell = Target.PivotCell
IsFromPivotTable = True
NotFromPivot:
On Error GoTo 0
If IsFromPivotTable Then
    Set PComBar = Application.CommandBars("PivotTable Context Menu")
    Set PControl = PComBar.Controls("Additional Actions")
    On Error Resume Next
    With PControl
        Call .Controls("My Drillthrough Action").Delete
        .Enabled = True
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set DControl = PControl.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, Temporary:=True, Before:=1)
    With DControl
        .Style = msoButtonIconAndCaption
        .Caption = "My Drillthrough Action"
        .FaceId = 786
    End With
    On Error Resume Next
        Set BControl = PControl.Controls("(No Actions Defined)")
        With BControl 'This does not work and throws error if do not suppress with On Error
            .Enabled = True
            .Visible = False
            .Caption = "Hello there"
        End With
    On Error GoTo 0
End If
```

So, the last section **With BControl ... End With** does not work at all, and throws an error "Automation Error".
I can successfully edit **Additional Actions** itself, like enable it, but I would like to get rid of **(No Actions Defined)** control, or replace it with my own.
Note, that **Call .Controls("(No Actions Defined)").Delete** does not work either.
How can I do that?
I tried to google the problem, but no luck...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you can't add to that menu. You could, however, add to the context menu itself:

```
Sub test()
Dim PCell As PivotCell
Dim PComBar As CommandBar
Dim DControl As CommandBarControl
Dim target As Excel.Range

    Set target = ActiveCell
    On Error Resume Next
    Set PCell = ActiveCell.PivotCell
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not PCell Is Nothing Then
        Set PComBar = Application.CommandBars("PivotTable Context Menu")
        Set DControl = PComBar.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, Temporary:=True, Before:=1)
        With DControl
            .Style = msoButtonIconAndCaption
            .Caption = "My Drillthrough Action"
            .FaceId = 786
        End With
    End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Actually, I can add my button to "Additional Actions" and it works fine. I cannot remove already existing default item "(No Actions Defined)" from there.

Comment: Sorry, I see now that's what you said.